# Non-ASCII printable characters in sshd banner

Tags: ssh, colors, unicode

It's possible to configure a banner for `sshd` that is to be displayed *as a connection is opened*, via `Banner /etc/motd.ssh` in `sshd_config`.  Note that this is displayed *before* the authentication occurs, and even when an interactive shell is not launched (e.g. via `scp`).

If this banner contains characters outside of the printable ASCII range, they seem to be escaped, however.  Is there any way to either disable this escaping, or an alternative way to send textual output back to the client on connection which supports such characters outside of the printable-ASCII range?

This would be useful both for colour escape sequences and Unicode characters.

- Related: [Colorful ssh banner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76184/colorful-ssh-banner) (not a duplicate, however, as this question is about another kind of banner, not about color)

Comment: This Q is asking if it's possible to display special characters using the SSH Banner feature, right?

Comment: @slm yes, or if there is an alternative to it, if it's not possible. I suspect the answer is 'no', but I couldn't find any definitive answer when searching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Mention #1 - LinuxFromScratch project

One place that it's mentioned is in the Linux From Scratch project. I found this page titled: [/etc/issue (Customizing your logon)](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/logon.html).

*excerpt*

> The /etc/issue file is a plain text file which will also accept certain Escape sequences (see below) in order to insert information about the system. There is also the file issue.net which can be used when logging on remotely. ssh however, will only use it if you set the option in the configuration file and will also not interpret the escape sequences shown below.

#### Mention #2 - SecurityFocus Forum post

As additional evidence that this is not possible there is this excerpt from a forum post titled: [Re: ssh and banners Aug 18 2009 01:20PM](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/121/505842/30/450/threaded), that discusses the function that implements the printing of the banner in OpenSSH.

*excerpt*

> After doing some more digging, I found that there is a function in the ssh 
>   source (specifically sshconnect2.c) called "input_userauth_banner" that 
>   displays the banner from the server. The text of the banner is now being 
>   filtered through another function called "strnvis" that encodes non-printable 
>   ascii characters as printable text, ie: octal codes. This is why the ansi 
>   escape sequence is displayed as "\033[". The documentation for strnvis 
>   doesn't mention any security issues, only "unexpected behavior" that could be 
>   associated with non-printable characters.

#### Mention #3 - OpenSSH Release Notes + RFC's

Lastly I encourage you to look through the release notes for OpenSSH. They're here as well as the RFC's that govern the SSH v1 & v2 specifications.

- http://www.openssh.com/txt/

This [RFC covers](http://www.openssh.com/txt/rfc4252.txt) some of the behavior of the `Banner` feature. This section "5.4.  Banner Message" covers the details of why this isn't allowed. This paragraph is where is says this is explicitly disallowed.

*excerpt*

> If the 'message' string is displayed, control character filtering, discussed in [SSH-ARCH], SHOULD be used to avoid attacks by sending terminal control characters.

#### Additional references (per @hildred)

- http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/54481
- https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2058

Comment: This is exactly what I'm currently using. `/etc/issue.net` is a common name for `Banner`, and as mentioned in the question non-printable ASCII characters seem to be escaped by `sshd` here.  Sorry, my question might've been a bit unclear.

Comment: @FireFly - I think the gist of that comment is that ssh's banner facility will not allow you to include escape sequences by design. That's what you want confirmation of, right?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. I'll accept this for the time being, but I was of course *hoping* for a workaround instead. :P but alas, seems it's not possible.

Comment: @FireFly - I don't think you're going to get what you want. I usually do it in the .bashrc or motd afterwards if I want control chars + colors. See my updates. I added all the details that show that it's not possible.

Comment: @FireFly - I remember looking into this several years ago and hitting the wall too and wondering why, I just shelved it, but now we know that it's for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The openssh client has a bug in its unsafe character filter which instead of filtering control characters, filters out everything but printable ascii (the spec calls for printable utf8) a [patch](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/attachment.cgi?id=2440&action=diff#lib/Makefile_sec1) to the client will fix this.

Comment: It’s not a bug. It’s unwillingness to make complex investigations about $LANG, $TERM, and correct methods of output in the current environment. As well as a (hyper)caution due to existence of old ASCII- and ISO-8859-oriented terminal emulator software that can be confused by high-bit-set octets, especially from the C1 (\200–\237) range.

Comment: The C1 range is not the issue, it is rejecting everything greater than 0x80. if it was just a C1 issue it would accept properly formatted utf8 as the c1 range is undefined in unicode. $TERM is not an issue as most of C0 is also escaped the $LANG check is simple, either it accepts utf8 or it does not. if it does not the current behavior is only slightly broken. If you are using utf8 the current behavior breaks laws in china and anywhere that legal notices are required in languages other than english. bottom line: bug.

Comment: Did you mention the word *octet*? Half of UTF-8 continuation byte range (\200–\277) strays into what would be C1 in an ISO-8859-compatible encoding. For example: 2×2 encoded in UTF-8 (can you feed it to “LANG=C od -c”?) contains a “C1” byte.

Comment: No I did not use the word octet, as it does not cleanly apply to variable length encodings like utf8, which is what the network encoding is here, not iso-8859, not latin1, not ascii, utf8. You are correct that the safe character filter does treat it as octets. That is the bug. Further if memory serves it does not check for the C1 range, but any byte with the high bit set.

Comment: We don’t discuss network protocols and conventions. We discuss how to output internationalized characters in an arbitrary terminal environment. Ī̲ agree that $LANG with “utf8” might suggest to proceed with a safe UTF-8 text, but the problem is due to legacy (ISO-8859-oriented and alike) **terminal environments.** In this case (where we assume a reasonable user won’t set a UTF-8 locale) there are namely unsafe *octets*, not unsafe characters.

Comment: By the way, what did [this Damien Miller’s diff](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/attachment.cgi?id=2440&action=diff) result in?

Comment: His patch filters for printable well defined utf8. I agree that dealing with other charsets is an issue, but when the protocol specifies utf8, if you assume a eight bit terminal the appropriate action is to convert to the local charset. Assuming that you have ascii compatible terminals just assures the rest of the world of american arrogance. Red flag linux uses a patch that just removes the character filter. I am not sure that is correct either as they assume local charset. Also I would be more inclined to believe that a user or distributor would set utf8 as it is the common recommendation

Comment: to solve charset issues, the default in debian, and derivatives. I believe it is also the default for red hat, putty and suse.

Comment: PuTTY is irrelevant to the question discussed, because it relies only on *its own terminal emulator* (not win32 console) and hence may output the banner independently of session settings, as it wishes. Unix-style `ssh` client is another deal: to interact with a user, it relies on a kind of external API called “tty”.