# What are some methods I can use to create colorful MOTD messages when logging in?

Tags: login, colors, motd

From time to time I've come across colorful ASCII art styled messages when logging into a server. How are these messages constructed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***NOTE:** None of these will work with SSH's banner facility. See this U&L Q&A titled: [Non-ASCII printable characters in sshd banner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109038/non-printable-ascii-characters-in-sshd-banner?lq=1) for [reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109045/7453) as to why SSH omits this feature.*

#### Generic Colouriser

[Generic Colouriser](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html) could be used for this application. It has the capability to identify via regular expressions bits of text, and then assign a color to any that match.

```
# this is probably a pathname
regexp=/[\w/\.]+
colour=green
count=more
```

This will match /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin/, /etc/init.d/syslogd and similar strings and paint it with green.

Another example:

```
regexp=^-{1,2}\s{0,1}$
colours=red
count=block
-
regexp=^\s{0,5}$
colours=default
count=unblock
```

This will turn all correctly formatted mail signatures red.

#### Screenshot

[image: ss of syslog]

#### MOTD Maker

Came across this GUI, [MOTD Maker](http://edeca.net/wp/programs/motd-maker/) which allows you to interactively create your MOTD and save it as a text file. App is a windows application but ran find under Wine.

[image: ss of motd maker #1]

[image: ss of motd maker #2]

#### Linux Logo

This one, [linux_logo](http://www.deater.net/weave/vmwprod/linux_logo/), has been around since I started using Linux daily in 1997, so it's an oldie but it still looks good and has a surprising array of features.

This one is more a logo with system related stats being displayed, but you can incorporate your own text so it's related to your question.

[image: linux_logo #1]

[image: linux_logo #2]

#### ScriptEchoColor

[ScriptEchoColor](http://scriptechocolor.sourceforge.net/) simplifies Linux terminal text colorizing, formatting and several steps of script coding.

**For Example**

```
1. Wait for a key press:
    echoc -w
    echoc -w "When you ready"

2. Ask a question and receive an \"yes/no\" answear:
    if echoc -q "Ready to continue"; then
        echo "Hello"
    fi
```

[image: ss ScriptEchoColor]

#### References

- [Generic Colouriser Main Page](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html)
- [Generic Colouriser README](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc/README.txt)
- [Generic Colouriser Downloads](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc/)